# ANDROID/SQLite Search a record

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox

I'm developing a symptoms checker application. My application has a `listview` with checkbox (from `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`).

After checking the following symptoms and clicking the **DONE** button, the app should display the possible conditions the user may have. Information are already stored in my prepopulated `SQLite` database. For your info, please refer to this screenshot:

[image]

This is what I have so far: (**Symptoms.java**)

```
       public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /*Intent i = new Intent(this, SymptomsResult.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();*/

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
      dbHelper.openDataBase();

      String c = dbHelper.getData();

    String selected = "";
    int cntChoice = lv.getCount();

    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

    for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){

        if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
            selected += lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
        }

    }

    c.equals(selected);

    dbHelper.close();


    Toast.makeText(this, selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       

}
```

**DBHelper.java**

```
     public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.fps.myheartfirst/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "mhfDB";
private static String KEY_CONDITIONS = "conditions";
private static String KEY_SYMPTOMS = "symptoms";
private static String DB_TABLE = "tblSymptoms";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    myDataBase = null;

     if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path

            myDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
            myDataBase.close();


        try {
            copyDataBase(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */

private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database doesn't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public String getData() {

    String search = "";

    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_CONDITIONS + " FROM " + DB_TABLE + 
            " WHERE " + KEY_SYMPTOMS + " = '" 
    + search + "'", null);
            //new String[] { name }, null, null, null);

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONDITIONS);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        search = search + c.getString(iRow);
    }

    return search;

}
```

My problem is that, how can I put the String query for my Symptoms class? I'm kinda new to database programming so I beg your pardon.

I believe in this line I have to put something:

```
   c.equals(selected);

    dbHelper.close();


    Toast.makeText(this, selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

So a toast will be displayed to user to view the possible conditions. Does anybody here know how to accomplish this? I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getData( String search) {

 Cursor c = myDataBase.query("SELECT " + KEY_CONDITIONS + " FROM " + DB_TABLE + 
        " WHERE " + KEY_SYMPTOMS + " = '" 
+ search + "'", null);

Cursor c = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE ,KEY_SYMPTOMS+ " = ?",new String[]{search},null,null,null);


int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONDITIONS);

for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
    search = search + c.getString(iRow);
}

return search;

}
```

pass the search word to `getData()` method

Comment: why do I need to use another cursor? Can you explain? Thanks

Comment: and you have a missing argument to it.

Comment: Hello I really need assistance here. I did what you told me but it's not displaying the result.

Comment: just replace getData() in ur DBHelper class and replace onClick code block

public void onClick(View v) {  
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
      dbHelper.openDataBase();  
    String selected = "";
    int cntChoice = lv.getCount();
    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
    for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){
        if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
 selected += lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
selected=dbHelper.getData(selected);
        }
    }
    dbHelper.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      

}

Answer (score 0):

Change the **getData** method as given below -

```
public String getData(String [] symptoms) {
    String search = null;
    Cursor c = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String [] {KEY_CONDITIONS}, KEY_SYMPTOMS + "= ? ", symptoms, null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();

    while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
        search = "" + c.getString(0);
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    return search;

}
```

And in the **Symptoms** class - change the **onClick** as -

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    ArrayList<String> alSymptoms = new ArrayList<String>();


    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    try {

        dbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        dbHelper.openDataBase();

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {

        throw sqle;

    }



    String selected = "";

    int cntChoice = lv.getCount();

    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

    for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {

        if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {

            //Log.i("Selected", lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            //selected += lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
            alSymptoms.add(lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
        }

    }
    String [] symptoms = alSymptoms.toArray(new String[alSymptoms.size()]);

    String c = dbHelper.getData(symptoms);

    Toast.makeText(this, c, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    dbHelper.close();
}
```